# Showing a contradiction involving inequalities

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, optimization

We are asked to choose $(a,b) \geq (0,0)$ such that
$$f(t-a)+rf(Ka-b)+r^2f(t+Kb)$$ is maximized. We know that $f$ is strictly increasing, and has strict concavity.
Moreover, $f$ is differentiable function with $f'(0) \rightarrow  + \infty$. And $t>0$, $0<r<1$, $K \in (0, \frac{1}{r}).$
Show that the solution to this problem is $(a^*,0)$, where $a^*$ is solution to the problem of maximizing(by choosing $a'$)
$$f(t-a')+rf(Ka')$$

*Here is my attempt:*

Assume to the contrary that there exists $(k_1,k_2)$ with $(k_1,k_2) \neq (a^*,0)$ such that $f(t-a)+rf(Ka-b)+r^2f(t+Kb)$ attains its maximum. Then
$$\underbrace{f(t-k_1)+rf(Kk_1-k_2)}_{\text{< $f(t-a^*)+rf(Ka^*)$}}+r^2f(t+Kk_2)>f(t-a^*)+rf(Ka^*)+r^2f(t)$$
To obtain contradiction, it suffices to show that $r^2f(t+Kk_2)<r^2f(t)$. However, $r^2, K>0$ being positive and $f$ being a strictly increasing function, it is a bit trickier to show the last part. It might be simple but after hours of work, looks like I am missing something.

Comment: Try to differentiate the function w.r.t $a$ and $b$. Yous hould find an optimum when both derivatives are $0$. I believe you also need $a \ge b$ property to hold.

Comment: I couldn't understand how I could differentiate the function as I believe it's single-valued function on R.

Comment: Possibly the functional you study (say $F$) decreases along lines $k_2 \rightarrow (k_1,k_2)$ for any $k_1$, so that you can optimize in 2 passes, first along $k_2$ and then $k_1$? $F(a',0) \geq F(k_1,0) \geq F(k_1,k_2)$

Comment: You can use partial differentiation in the parameters $a$ and $b$.

Comment: While $f(x)$ is a function of one variable (single-valued is a bit redundant in this context), the expression $f(t-a)+rf(Ka-b)+r^2f(t+Kb)$ is a function (if I understand) of two variables, $a$ and $b$.  It might be expeditious (since this is your objective function, to be maximized) to give it a name.  In any case it is important to identify the known (or "fixed") values of $r,t$.